# Error condition if else in prolog

Tags: prolog

Could someone tell me what's wrong in my If else in my search, in the sublist.

Because when the size is 0, the conditional works, but if the value becomes 1,2 and 3 it presents an error, but the relational operators are not correct?

If the variable length has size = 0, the condition works, but if the variable length has size 3 it has an error.

Error is:

Exception: >=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.

```
subList([], []). 
subList(List1,List2):-
      concatenate(List1,List2,Result1),
      equalelements(Result1,Result2),
      counting(Result2,Length),
      Length =< 2
   -> false
   ;  Length >= 3
   -> true.

searchdisease([],_).
searchdisease(Symptoms,Disease) :-
   disease(Ls, Disease),
   subList(Symptoms, Ls).

counting([ ],0).
counting([_| T], N) :-
   counting(T, N1),
   N is N1 + 1.

concatenate(L1, L2, NL) :-
   append(L1, L2, L12),
   msort(L12, NL).
```

Comment: Lenght is return variable of the size of the list, time it returns size 0, time it returns size 1 or size 2,3,4, etc. So I check if the size of the list is less than or equal to 2 or greater or equal to 3.

Comment: I have indented your rules: now you see that `Length` is uninstantiated for `Length >= 3`

Comment: Length is the return of the predicate Counting, which returns a list size in the variable lenght.

Comment: I want a make a condition for the size of the list, just that.

Comment: @AndersonMendes: Please do not change the indentation: The way I changed it corresponds to what Prolog sees. You changed it to what you want, but what you have not written.

Comment: Sorry I was adding the other predicates. I want a condition for the size of the list, the predicate that returns the list size is counting, after return I get the variable length use to return false or true.

Comment: If `Length =< 2` fails, then **certainly** `Length >= 3` will produce an error, because `Length` is no longer instantiated!

Comment: @false Now I understand false, but is not there a way to do these two checks?

Comment: Why do you need these two checks? Both mean exactly the same as `Length >= 3` alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem with priorities of operators. Note that Prolog ignores the precise indentation you use.  Instead it takes operators into account. So you need to add round brackets accordingly.

Most probably you want the following:

```
subList([], []). 
subList(List1,List2):-
   concatenate(List1,List2,Result1),
   equalelements(Result1,Result2),
   counting(Result2,Length),
   (  Length =< 2
   -> false
   ;  Length >= 3
   -> true
   ).
```

On the other hand, why not simply replace the comparisons for `Length` by a single goal: `Length >= 3`.